# sql server, aggregate (count) on many columns in table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which I have simplified to that below. It actually extends up to Type60

```
   Number     | Type1     | Type2     | Type3     | Type4
   ------------------------------------------------------
   1          | 1         | 1         | 1         | 0
   2          | 1         | 1         | 1         | 0
   3          | 1         | 1         | 1         | 0   
   4          | 0         | 2         | 0         | 1   
   5          | 0         | 2         | 1         | 0   
   6          | 0         | 2         | 0         | 1
   7          | 1         | 1         | 1         | 0
   8          | 1         | 1         | 0         | 1
   9          | 1         | 2         | 1         | 0
   10         | 0         | 2         | 0         | 1
```

The output that I want, is like below (extended to Name60)

```
   Name     | Value     | CountOfValue 
   -----------------------------------
   Name1    | 0         | 4 
   Name1    | 1         | 6    
   Name2    | 1         | 5 
   Name2    | 2         | 5 
   Name3    | 0         | 6 
   Name3    | 1         | 4 
   Name4    | 0         | 4 
   Name4    | 1         | 6
```

To get there, I have been doing:

```
select 'Name1' as Name, Type1, Count(Number)
from table1
group by Type1

union

select 'Name2' as Name, Type2, Count(Number)
from table1
group by Type2

union

select 'Name3' as Name, Type3, Count(Number)
from table1
group by Type3

union

select 'Name4' as Name, Type4, Count(Number)
from table1
group by Type4
```

upto Name60 etc

this take a fair while to run,

Is there a more efficent (faster) way to do the same thing does anyone know?

Thanks, Gary

Comment: Look into [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try UNPIVOT.

```
SELECT Name, [values] AS Value, Count(*) AS CountOfValue
FROM
(
    SELECT REPLACE([Type], 'Type', 'Name') AS Name, [values]
    FROM #testPivot
    UNPIVOT ([values] FOR [type] IN 
            (Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4) -- ETC to Type60
    ) AS unpvt
) AS test
GROUP BY Name, [values]
ORDER BY Name, Value
```

You'd still have to put in all the Type1 to Type 60 in the UNPIVOT. Check out [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).